# Spring boot no me arranca en tomcat

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring, tomcat

Estoy creado un servicio rest pero al probar desde el servidor tomcat no me funciona.

Tengo configurado el package en el pom

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

también la dependecia:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

y tengo esta clase que me ha generado el start.spring.io:

```
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

    public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(PersonasApplication.class);
    }

}
```

war generado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es webapps de tomcat
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy usando tomcat 8.5, ¿sabeis que puede estar pasando?. Gracias!!

Comment: ¿Tienes algún mensaje de error en Tomcat o durante la compilación? ¿sabes si se genera correctamente el fichero war?

Comment: en principio, en la carpeta target se encuentra el war, añado la captura y en los logs de arranque me viene como cuando si lo arrancaras sin proyecto.

Comment: y ese war que generaste, lo deployaste en el tomcat?...o simplemente lo dejaste ahi solito en el directorio target?...la otra opcion es que ejecutes tu programa como una app springboot y eso automaticamente deberia ejecutar el tomcat de forma embebida

Comment: importe el war en el apache tomcat . Si como app springboot va, pero quiero aprender a configurarlo en el servidor

Answer (score 0):

creo que la dendencia debe ser

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```